# Setting line number in EditText to cover the whole screen

Tags: android

I want to show A LOT of text in my Android app.
So I thought about putting it into an EditText, and divide the text into pages, where each page fills the whole screen, and to go to the next screen you have to swipe.
The difficult part is to divide the text into parts.
How can I calculate the number of chars that I have to put inside each page, so it fills the whole screen?

Comment: Just curious, why you don't want to use `ScrollView` if you have lot of text?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I think that showing that much text in one long ScrollView isn't that easy to use for the user.. It's the same reason that all ebook readers use the way I described above and not a single long long page :)

Comment: Interesting! Sounds right. I'll be surprised if someone hasn't asked this before. On quick search I found that you asked a very similar question almost 2 years back(with accepted answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034660/make-text-fit-exactly-as-the-screen-size. If the answers don't work, you may include in the question why they don't provide you the solution you want and how your this question is a bit different from previous one:)